# Custom theme : deprecation warnings from Dart Sass about !global assignments

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material2

After updating to Angular 10, a bunch of errors started to appear at compile time, all related to Material custom theming and Dart Sass.

Example :

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: As of Dart Sass 2.0.0, !global assignments won't be able to
declare new variables. Consider adding `$mat-form-field-legacy-dedupe: null` at the root of the
stylesheet.

     ╷
6155 │   $mat-form-field-legacy-dedupe: $mat-form-field-legacy-dedupe + 0.00001 !global;
     │   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     ╵
    node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss 6155:3  -mat-form-field-legacy-label-floating()
    node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss 6206:9  mat-form-field-legacy-typography()
    node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss 6726:3  mat-form-field-typography()
    node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss 6871:3  angular-material-typography()
    node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss 6899:3  mat-core()
    src/theme.scss 2:1                                   @import
    stdin 36:13                                          root stylesheet
```

All errors are triggered either by `@include mat-core();` or `@include angular-material-theme($my-theme);`, both present in my custom `theme.scss` file.

But the incriminated `!global` statements are all coming from `_theming.scss` file in `@angular/material` package.

I tried following the advice "Consider adding `$mat-form-field-legacy-dedupe: null` at the root  of the stylesheet", with no success, whether I add this instruction in `styles.scss`, `theme.scss` or both.

The custom theme used to work and I changed nothing in it; it is basically structured as follows:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@include mat-core(); // 1st source of errors

// palettes definitions using mat-palette(…)

$my-theme: mat-light-theme(…)

@include angular-material-theme($my-theme); // 2nd source of errors

// a bunch of CSS rules
```

Disabling the custom theme (commenting out the `theme.scss` file contents for example) of course solves the problem.

I looked for answers online for a while but found nothing.

All Angular libraries are up to date. Deleting `node_modules` and reinstalling dependencies didn't solve the issue.

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Angular team already has a [pending PR to fix the deprecated syntax](https://github.com/angular/material/pull/12112).

In the meantime, you can update your `sass` to the latest version (1.35.2 as of this writing), then update your loader configuration to set the `quietDeps` option.  I don't use the Angular CLI directly, but if you've "ejected" to regular Webpack, you can put this in your style rule:

```js
{
  loader: "sass-loader",
  options: {
    sassOptions: { quietDeps: true }
  }
}
```